# How to mention the assetlinks.json file in a secondary domain?

Tags: javascript, html, json, progressive-web-apps

My assetlinks.json file is present in `2.example.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json` however it is for `1.example.com`.

How to mention the file in `1.example.com`, so that it can be used.

Comment: Arrange for the Web server powering `1.example.com` to return your JSON for `https://1.example.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json`. The details of doing that would depend on the Web server and your overall configuration and are not tied to Android.

Comment: What is the html snippet that I will use for that?

Comment: I rather doubt it would be an "HTML snippet". Talk to the team that is managing your Web server and explain to them what you need.